# Backup/Restore Shared Services Provider on SharePoint MOSS

Tags: sharepoint, moss, backup, restore, sharedservicesprovider

I'm having serious issues with backing up and restoring a shared services provider.

Using the Central Administration backup I run the backup to s:\

This completes fine.

I then from another SharePoint Server choose to restore a backup and point it to the UNC path \machineipaddress\s$\spbr00DF

I have given everyone full access to s:\ on the source server.

All I get back from SharePoint is this:

Directory \machineipaddress\s$\spbr00DF does not exist or the SQL Server service account and the BI_WEB\Administrator service account do not have permission to read or write to the backup folder. Specify a different directory.

Would appreciate anyones thoughts on this.

reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc896556.aspx

All the best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens when you specify \\machineipaddress\s$ as the folder for the restore?

Answer (score 1):

Hey I'm new here but just wanted to add my two cents.

I was having the same issue and found one of the above users was correct, the error was generated because a system account did not have access to the share.

On our server we got the same error. When we created our Sharepoint sites we selected the Network Service account to run the site. I went to the share and added the Network Service account with Full Control and now the restore works.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

First take a backup of all the databases. The following are must..
1. Farm Configuration database
2. All the content databases (for all web apps)
3. The central admin database.

If you want you can also take a backup of the Shared services and search databases.

once you have a copy of all these databases restored on a different database server do the following.

1. Run a PSConfig wizard on the new farm and connect to the restored config database.
2. Provision the central admin (using the config wizard or the command line)
3. Create new web applications with the temp databases (you cant create a web app with a preexisting database) do this for each web app.
4. From the central admin delete the temp database from the web app and attach the restored database for each web app (if that fails from the GUI, do it via stsadm -o attachcontentdb).
5. Start and configure the WSS search and Office search on the farm.
6. Go to Shared services> restore Shared services
   select the web application for the SSP and mysites and enter the database names of the Shared services, search etc and hit OK.

Answer (score 1):

Your unc path is not correct, it should be::

```
\\machineipaddress\spbr00DF
```

You don't need the `s$` part also ensure your 'spbr00DF' is shared and verify that 'spbr00DF' is its share name.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the issue stemmed from SharePoint using the specified system account to do the restore, even though it says that either the system account or the current user must have access.

We moved SharePoint to a totally new environment recently, and I was so fed up with the included backup/restore system that I ended up just backing up the relevant databases, creating new web applications in the new environment, and attaching the databases to them. You can remove content databases from sites through Central Admin, but you'll need to use stsadm to reattach. This worked flawlessly for me, and may suit your needs.